# Using Metro in place of Weblogic Webservices Stack

Tags: web-services, stack, weblogic, swap, java-metro-framework

I am attempting to use Metro web services in place of the default Weblogic webservices stack contained in weblogic.jar.

The problem comes when trying to get WebLogic to use the metro stack before its own.

The steps I have taken so far is to reference the webservices-rt.jar in the project.  So far I am getting this error while deploying the ear file....

Caused By: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "DATETIME" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the referring class, javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeConstants, and the class loader (instance of ) for the field's resolved type, javax/xml/namespace/QName, have different Class objects for that type

**UPDATES:**

Most Recent Error is:  "class javax.xml.namespace.QName has neither @WebSerivce nor @WebServiceProvider"  Strange that it is looking for @Webservice on a QName object:

1. Contents of Application-Weblogic.xml

`<wls:prefer-application-packages>

        <wls:package-name>com.ctc.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>com.sun.xml.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>com.sun.istack.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>com.sun.msv.datatype.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>com.sun.msv.driver.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>com.sun.msv.grammar.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>com.sun.msv.reader.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>com.sun.msv.relaxns.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>com.sun.msv.scanner.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>com.sun.msv.util.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>com.sun.msv.verifier.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>com.sun.msv.writer.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>com.sun.wsit.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>javax.jws.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>javax.xml.bind.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>javax.xml.soap.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>javax.xml.stream.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>javax.xml.ws.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>javax.xml.activation.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>javax.xml.annotation.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>javax.xml.mail.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>javax.xml.security.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>javax.xml.registry.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>javax.xml.rpc.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>javax.xml.crypto.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>javanet.staxutils.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>jp.gr.xml.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>org.codehaus.stax2.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>org.glassfish.gmbal.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>org.iso_relax.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>org.jcp.xml.dsig.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>org.jvnet.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>org.relaxng.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>antlr.</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.lang.</wls:package-name>

    </wls:prefer-application-packages>`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using the FilteringClassLoader which is configured in weblogic-application.xml deployment descriptor.  You can instruct WebLogic to load classes from the application in favor of the libraries that are included with WebLogic.  The descriptor element is  and you specify the Java packages you want to load from the application.

If you are using WebLogic 10.3.4 you can use the ClassLoader Analysis to analyze the packages that are in conflict.

Check out my presentation here: [SlideShare.net](http://www.slideshare.net/jeffreyawest/weblogic-filtering-classloader-and-classloader-analysis-tool-demo) and my demo of the CAT here: [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArLTKapjV_8)

Comment: WebLogic Server Version: 10.3.3.0  :(

However I have made some progress since I posted the question... I will update with my findings and if you can help that would be great!

Comment: While I haven't tried it in anger, I'd thought that the Classloader Analysis app can be run on earlier versions of WebLogic Server, it's just that it's only provided with 10.3.4. Is that the case, Jeff?

Comment: Not sure, to be honest.  Perhaps you are missing a library in the application that you are deploying?  If you could use WLS 10.3.4 and try to use the CAT it may give you insight on how to fix the problem on 10.3.3.  CAT is only in 10.3.4